# Shared variable in Haskell parMap

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have a computation which does essentially the following:

```
f :: [a] -> ([b],Bool)
```

This function can actually be written

```
f = foldr h ([],False) . map g
    where h (b,bool) (bs,boolSoFar) = (b:bs,bool || boolSoFar)
```

where `g :: a -> (b,Bool)` is some function that takes a lot of time.  Also f is usually called on small lists, so it seemed like it might be fun to try computing the map in parallel.  This can be accomplished with Control.Parallel.Strategies parMap.  So now we use

```
f = foldr h ([],False) . parMap rseq g
    where h (b,bool) (bs,boolSoFar) = (b:bs, bool || boolSoFar)
```

This all works great. Now, you'll note that there is a sequential optimization that can be performed in the first definition of `f`.  Namely, I can use map-fold fusion to write it as a single fold, so one loop through the list.  However, then I lose the benefits of doing parallel.

Now, one might say that in the second definition of `f`, looping through list again is not so bad, so why not just do it.  I guess what I am thinking is that if Haskell had mutable variables, then one could just, in the body of map, update this boolean variable (I guess you would have to lock and unlock it).  Are there any suggestions for doing things like this?

Comment: I highly doubt that using a mutable variable to contain the boolean value is going to make it any faster.  Have you run a profiler on your code to see where the slowdowns occur?  You may be too focused on optimizing something simple when your efficiency problem lies elsewhere.  Are you sure that `g` is getting evaluated in parallel, or is it creating thunks in parallel and letting the single-core `foldr` do the evaluation?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment.  Actually, I want to know more if this is possible.  I have been playing with profiling, and what not.  Certainly the majority  of time is spent in the map.  I know this, and it is stated in the question.  But I have seen this pattern come up in more than one place in my code, where I do something in parallel, and then something else in sequence -- and the sequential part is something tacked on to the end of a computation and could be done with a shared variable in the parallel part.  So I'm asking how to do this in Haskell.

Comment: It's certainly possible to use `MVar`s to do this, but I think you might find that the overhead of using a mutable variable would, in most cases, vastly outweigh doing a quick second loop.  It would depend on your specific problem, though.  I can definitely imagine where there could be cases that you would want to do something like that.

Comment: I just wrote up something that was fairly naive as a proof of concept.  Used Chan instead of MVar, and I will be the first to admit that the code isn't fully optimized, but the difference between `map` and `parMap` was negligible, and the difference between those and using Chans was an order of magnitude slower.  This is a good example of how GHC can handle things quite well by itself without the need to introduce complicated threading mechanisms.

Comment: How can I tell whether I am creating thunks in parallel and evaluating by foldr as normal or actually evaluating in parallel?  Is there a way I can profile and see whether the overhead of setting up parallel execution denies the benefits of doing things parallel?

Comment: There are a couple techniques that are described at length here http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness, but the general gist is to use a) pattern matching, b) the strict `$!` operator, and c) BangPatterns.  Personally, I like using `$!` because it's short and sweet, but it isn't appropriate in every instance, so BangPatterns are quite useful as well, like with `let !result = expr in result`.

Comment: use http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/packages/parallel-3.2.0.3/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html and make your own `Strategy`

Answer (score 1):

What this is going to wind up being is actually a traversal under the lazy writer `Applicative` with the writer state being `Bool`, since `(False, (||))` forms a monoid. You'll want the [`unamb`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb) package as well, so you can get the value the first time any of the parallel calls of `g` returns `True`.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.Unamb

newtype EvalWB a = EvalWB { runEvalWB :: Eval (a, Bool) }

instance Functor EvalWB where
  fmap f (EvalWB m) = EvalWB $ fmap (\ ~(a, b) -> (f a, b)) m

instance Applicative EvalWB where
  pure a = EvalWB $ pure (a, False)

  EvalWB mf <*> EvalWB ma = EvalWB $ (\ ~(f, bf) ~(a, ba) -> (f a, por bf ba)) <$> mf <*> ma
```

And then you have

```
f :: [a] -> ([b], Bool)
f l = runEval $ runEvalWB $ traverse (\a -> EvalWB $ rpar $ g a) l
```

This passes over the entire list in parallel, accumulating the values and flags lazily. It uses [`por`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/src/Data-Unamb.html#por) to short-circuit on the first `True` return.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use the State Monad ? changing the function `f` from:

```
f :: [a] -> ([b], Bool)
```

to:

```
f :: [a] -> State Bool [b]
```

You would just have to update the value of your State through one folding of your list, no ? I'm not sure if you can apply it with the parallel thing, though. My knowledge of Haskell is somewhat limited.

Comment: No, you can't do this in parallel.

Comment: I guess a bit of detail might be in order: you can't do that in parallel because [`State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:State) is represented as `s -> (a, s)`, and the state is propagated along the computation by `>>=`, so each part of the computation has to be strictly sequenced relative to each other part of the computation.  (The other `State` monads work similarly.)